# Sine-Gordon equation solved by SoV

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

The Sine-Gordon eq reads: $$u_{tt}-u_{xx} + \sin u = 0$$

I am looking for a solution of the form $u(x,t) = 4 \arctan\big(\frac{A(t)}{B(x)}\big)$. Directly computing the derivatives we obtain:

$$u_{tt} = \frac{4}{\big(A^2+B^2\big)^2}\big(A_{tt}B(A^2+B^2) - 2 AA_t^2B\big)$$

$$-u_{xx} = \frac{4}{\big(A^2+B^2\big)^2}\big(AB_{xx}(A^2+B^2)-2ABB_x^2\big)$$

$$\sin(4\arctan(F)) = -4 \frac{F^3 -F}{(F^2+1)^2} = \frac{4}{\big(A^2+B^2\big)^2}\big(AB^3 -A^3B)$$

Factoring out the common term gives:

$$B_{xx}A(A^2+B^2) - 2AB_x^2B +A_{tt}B(A^2+B^2) - 2AA_t^2B + AB^3 - A^3B = 0.$$

At this point I hit a brick wall - how does one proceed forward here?

I happen to know that the solutions are $A= \frac{cos(\omega t)}{\omega}$ and $B  = \frac{\cosh (\sqrt{1-\omega^2}x)}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}$ yet I can't seem to figure out how to split the equation to the form $f(A) = g(B) = \text{constant}$.

Furthermore - since the equation I'm left with is symmetric under exchange $A\leftrightarrow B$ we should have $f(B) = -g(B)$. That would explain why $A$ is a $\cos$ and $B$ is a $\cosh$ but I don't see why the constant changes from $\omega \to \sqrt{1-\omega^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$B_{xx}A(A^2+B^2) - 2AB_x^2B +A_{tt}B(A^2+B^2) - 2AA_t^2B + AB^3 - A^3B = 0.$$
This is not the complete calculus, but just a manner to separate the variables.

Dividing by $AB$ :
$$\frac{B_{xx}}{B}(A^2+B^2) - 2B_x^2 +\frac{A_{tt}}{A}(A^2+B^2) - 2A_t^2 + B^2 - A^2 = 0.$$
Method of separation of variables. We look for a particular solution so that $A=A(t)$ and $B=B(x)$ :
$$\frac{B''}{B}(A^2+B^2) - 2B'^2 +\frac{A''}{A}(A^2+B^2) - 2A'^2 + B^2 - A^2 = 0.$$
$$\frac{B''}{B}A^2+\frac{A''}{A}B^2 +(A''A - 2A'^2 - A^2) +(B''B - 2B'^2+ B^2) = 0.$$
The separation of variables continues to be possible if 
$\quad\begin{cases}
\frac{A''}{A}=k_1\\
\frac{B''}{B}=k_2
\end{cases}$
$$k_2A^2+k_1B^2 +(A''A - 2A'^2 - A^2) +(B''B - 2B'^2+ B^2) = 0.$$
$$(k_2A^2+A''A - 2A'^2 - A^2)=-(k_1B^2+B''B - 2B'^2+ B^2)=C$$
$\begin{cases}
A''=k_1A\\
 - 2A'^2 +(k_1+k_2-1) A^2=C
\end{cases}$
$\quad\text{and}\quad$
$\begin{cases}
B''=k_2B\\
 - 2B'^2+(k_1+k_2+1) B^2=-C
\end{cases}$

I let you continue the boring calculus. Finally, among several possibilities, a full consistency is obtained with :
$$\begin{cases}
k_1=-\omega^2\\
k_2=1-\omega^2\\
C=-2
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad
\begin{cases}
A=\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\\
B=\frac{\cosh(\sqrt{1-\omega^2}\:x)}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Don't we lose generality when we claim $B''/B = k_1$?

Comment: Of course we lose generality. We lose generality even more, right from the start, with the method of separation of variables. I suppose that the game here was not to find a general solution, but to find, at least, one convenient solution.

Comment: That's a good point, I mostly encountered SoV in situations where we actually do get a whole basis as a solution.

Comment: We must keep in mind that the PDE $u_{tt}-u_{xx}+\sin(u)=0$ has an infinity of solutions (like other PDEs). The boundary and initial conditions are the key point to determine a solution among the general solutions. It has not been question of boundary nor initial conditions. So, it is possible that the particular solution found above don't satisfies the conditions and in this case the problem is unsolved. Also, it is possible that the particular solution found satisfies all the conditions and the problem is solve, despite the lack of generality of the method.